# How to effectively add a long list into DOM

Tags: javascript, list, dom, updating

I am trying to add dynamically more than 30k items into an unordered list. To get these items I use XMLHttpRequest. My question is how to do that effectively because typical approach, like this:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", "www/by_symbol.php?symbol=" + symbol, true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
xmlHttp.onload = onLoad;

function onLoad() {
    if (xmlHttp.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

takes more that 50 seconds. Is it typical?

Comment: 30K items on a UI? Who is going to browse so much of data? Why not implement lazy load and long scroll?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Great idea. Any sample or tutorial?

Comment: Why not just load 50 at a time and when you reach the bottom of the page, load another 50? There is an internet full of Ajax tutorials for loading long lists of data like this.

Comment: Basically you need to capture scroll event and if you are nearing the end of scroll then fire an ajax request to get next set of items http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/infinite-page-scroll/